# Cannot upload file and its details with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to upload image file along with it's details information with AngularJS. The file's details will be stored in JSON file on the server. But, it doesn't work. the return info from the server is just an empty array. I have no idea why my code doesn't work. I to experiment with Content-type, etc, etc... but still no luck.

my code:

```
<body>

    <div>
        <form ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="save()">
        Title :<input type="text" ng-model="file_details.title"><br>
        Summary: <input type="text" ng-model="file_details.summary"><br>
        File: <input type="file" file-upload><br>
        <button type="submit">save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Angular here
    (function(){
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.config(function($httpProvider){
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        });

        app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.file_details = {};

            $scope.files = [];

            //listening from fileUpload directive
            $scope.$on('fileSelected', function(event, args){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    //add the file object to scope's files collection
                    $scope.files.push(args.file);
                });
            });

            $scope.save = function(){
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'process.php',
                    transformRequest: function (data) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append("file_details", angular.toJson(data.file_details));
                        formData.append("file", data.files);
                    },
                    headers: {
                          'Content-Type': false

                    },
                    data: { 
                        file_details: $scope.file_details,
                        files: $scope.files
                    }
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // alert("success!");
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }

        }]);

        app.directive('fileUpload', function(){
            return{
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
                    elm.bind('change', function(event){
                        var files = event.target.files;
                        scope.$emit('fileSelected', { file: files });
                    });
                }
            }
        });


    })();
</script>
</body>
```

My server code (just to check if the data is sent, but it still returning an empty array):

```
print_r($_POST); die();
```